# Autocomplete in multiple rows, same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there any way to use the underline script for multiple rows in a table with the same id in its textfield?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#client').autocomplete({
        source:'autocomplete.clients.php',minLength:2
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use class name instead of id.You cannot use same id more than once.